# Inequalities of quotients of elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: inequality, automated-theorem-proving

Many inequalities regarding symmetric polynomials such as this are posed as problems

- http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/1997_USAMO_Problems/Problem_5 $$(a^3+b^3+abc)^{-1}+(b^3+c^3+abc)^{-1}+(a^3+c^3+abc)^{-1}\le(abc)^{-1}$$
- http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2003_USAMO_Problems/Problem_5 $$\frac{(2a + b + c)^2}{2a^2 + (b + c)^2} + \frac{(2b + c + a)^2}{2b^2 + (c + a)^2} + \frac{(2c + a + b)^2}{2c^2 + (a + b)^2} \le 8$$
- http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2004_USAMO_Problems/Problem_5 $$(a^5 - a^2 + 3)(b^5 - b^2 + 3)(c^5 - c^2 + 3) \ge (a+b+c)^3$$
- http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/1980_USAMO_Problems/Problem_5 $$\frac{x}{y + z + 1} + \frac{y}{z + x + 1} + \frac{z}{x + y + 1} \le 1 - (1 - x)(1 - y)(1 - z)$$

---

Is there an uniform method or algorithm to prove all true ones? We can assume they are input in some basis for [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of using $e^{iz}$ to prove trig identities or [venn diagrams](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223026/naive-set-theory-equality-proof/223048#223048) to prove set theory.

Comment: The theory containing these any many more is decidable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_Theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination) but I would like a more practical algorithm which just exploits the symmetry.

Comment: relevant http://mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/inequalities.pdf

Comment: You may be also interested in this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218811/bounding-schur-symmetric-polynomials-on-the-unit-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is work done in this regard and some interesting results. I recommend the following articles:

- [Cubic And Quartic Cyclic Homogenous Inequalities of Three Variables](http://files.ele-math.com/preprints/mia-16-09-pre.pdf)
- [Inequalities for Symmetric Means](http://www.haverford.edu/math/cgreene/papers/smean10-15.pdf)
- [Necessary and sucient conditions for symmetric homogeneous polynomial inequalities of degree four and six in real variables](http://www.tjnsa.com/includes/files/articles/Vol5_Iss5_307--320_Necessary_and_sucient_conditions_fo.pdf)

It is a fascinating area of research in which a lot remains to be discovered.