# how to proof symmetric differnce

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The symmetric difference can be expressed as the union of the two sets, minus their intersection- how to prove that ?

Comment: Isn't that almost the exact definition of a symmetric difference?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Symmetric_Difference

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320475/definition-of-symmetric-difference

Comment: yes it is and i shoud prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: To clarify the structure of the proof.

In general you can prove two sets $X$ and $Y$ are equal by showing 
$$x\in X\implies x\in Y\ \mbox{ and }\ x\in Y\implies x\in X,$$
which is analogues to

*any element of $X$ must also be an element of $Y$* and *any element of $Y$ must also be an element of $X$*.

That is what the proof below uses, with $X=\left(A\backslash B\right)\cup\left(B\backslash A\right)$ and $Y=\left(A\cup B\right)\backslash\left(A\cap B\right).$

---

So you want to prove the following equivalence:
$$A\Delta B=\left(A\cup B\right)\backslash\left(A\cap B\right),$$
where $A\Delta B$ is defined as $\left(A\backslash B\right)\cup\left(B\backslash A\right)$.

Prove as follows:

1. $x\in A \Delta B \implies x\in\left(A\cup B\right)\backslash\left(A\cap B\right)$
2. $x\in\left(A\cup B\right)\backslash\left(A\cap B\right) \implies x\in A \Delta B$

**Proof**:

1. $x\in A \Delta B\iff x\in\left(A\backslash B\right)\cup\left(B\backslash A\right)$. Assume $x\in A\backslash B$ (otherwise, just change $A$ and $B$). That implies:

   - $x\in A\cup B$.
   - $x\notin B$, which implies $x\notin A\cap B$.

And thus, $x\in\left(A\cup B\right)\backslash\left(A\cap B\right)$

2. In a similar way, see if you can do it :)

Comment: i will be right if i use only one of the proves or ?

Comment: No, you have to prove both statements. Basically, I prove $S=U$ by proving $x\in S\implies x\in U$ and $x\in U\implies x\in S$. Right now, we've only shown the first statement.

Comment: i don't understand what you have made in 1

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short proof. Note that $A \setminus (A \cap B) = A \setminus B$ for all $A, B$.

$(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$

$= (A \setminus (A \cap B))\ \cup\  (B \setminus (A \cap B))$

$=(A \setminus B)\ \cup\ (B \setminus A)$

$=A \bigtriangleup B$

Note, however, that some sources define symmetrical difference as the union of two sets minus their intersection, so depending on which definition you use you might just be able to refer to the definition.

Answer (score -1):

The symmetric difference is commonly defined as $ A \triangle B = A \setminus B \cup B \setminus A $

but now consider $x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$

This implies  $(x\in A$ or $x\in B)$ and $x\notin A \cap B$

which implies
$x\in A$  and $x\notin A \cap B$ or $x\in B$ and $x\notin A \cap B$

how can we write $x \in A$ and $x \notin A \cap B$? $x \in A \setminus B$

Result follows

Comment: why the downvote :(((